# Why would anyone use font-family: inherit;

Tags: css

I was editing a wordpress theme, and noticed that the stylesheet sets

```
font-family: inherit;
```

on most elements. Since all fonts are inherited by default, are there any cases where font-family: inherit; on an element has any effect, other then confusing firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
}

p {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

p.other-font {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

I think if you do it like this you will always have Helvetica for the other-font and the body font for all the rest. I think it's kinda unusual but that would be a case to use inherit

Comment: Wow, newer thought about that. That css would cause text in <em> tags within a <p> tag to change font back to verdana.

Comment: No, you would not always get the body font, only in browsers that support `inherit`. So while this is a possible use case, it it usually an unnecessary risk.

Answer (score 3):

By default, textareas and other various input boxes (and probably buttons too) do not inherit the parent font. In this case it would make sense to explicitly define them as `font-family:inherit` if that's the desired effect.